How can I format date in Odoo 15 QWeb report? i want to format specific date format not the
How can I format date in Odoo 15 Account Pay check form? for not using the actual date and not changing into the language date format? please help.
context_timestamp(datetime.datetime.now()).strftime('%m-%d-%Y')


You can force specify date format using t-options, if you have date field, like:
<span
    t-field="o.my_date_field"
    t-options="{'format': 'dd.MM.YYYY'}"
/>

If you are generating current time, without actual field, you can simply do like:
<span t-esc="datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%m-%d-%Y')"/>


the
datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%m-%d-%Y')
solve my problem for generating the current time but for force specific date its not working it will back to the default which is page['date']

i also try using this
t-esc="format_date(page['date'], date_format='%m-%d-%Y')"
but still shows the current date not the specific date.

and also what would i want to change is the 

Don't understand what you want. Formatting and having specific date (regardless of format) are two different things.

@zzaren009 The current date is always displayed because page['date'] contains the current date. Check how you set page['date'], you probably forgot to change it.

It solves using this code:
o.date.strftime('%m - %d - %Y')

but thanks by the way for the help guys appreciate it!

You can also use below code to solve the issue if you are using loop:-
<t t-esc="page[date].strftime('%m-%d-%Y')"/>

